# D3 json array not null constraint check?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Am using d3 collapsible tree for visualization.I just want to append the text based on the children array size .

Using the code like this:

```
        .append("svg:title")
         .text(function(d){
          if(d.type=="Start"){
            return "Name:"+d.name+"\n Click to view details";}  
          else if(d.type=="Z" && d.children!=null){
                return "Name:"+d.name+"\n Click to get Z";}
              else if(d.type=="Z" && d.children==null){
                return "Name:"+d.name+"\n no more children";}
          else{
                return "checking";}
        });
```

But this code not work for children is empty or not..How can i solve this issue. 
How can i make a condition based text?

JSON Value:
      {
"name":"first",
"children":[
{
"area":"A",
"name":"A-1",
"children":[
{
"area":"D",
"name":"A-11"
},
{
"area":"D",
"name":"A-22"
}
],
"type":"Z"
},
{
"area":"P",
"name":"B",
"children":[
],
"type":"Z"
},
{
"area":"P",
"name":"C",
"children":[
],
"type":"Z"
}
],
"type":"Start"
}

Comment: can you put code on jsfiddle/punker

Comment: @NitishKumar please consider my limitations on this code...i put the json array too

Comment: whats error are you getting ?

Comment: @NitishKumar i think it might not check the d.children part. i just wanna find the children[] json[] array empty or not

Comment: `d.children.length == 0`?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff d.children.length getting error..Collapsibal tree is not creating.

Comment: You would also have to check whether it's null, i.e. `d.children == null || d.children.length == 0`.